# deferred mail plesk, mail can't send mail out of server

Tags: linux, smtp, plesk, mail-server

My problem is about sending email out of the circle mail server, exemple:

From: name@mydomainename.com
To: name@gmail.com or any other domaine name

The message appeare on plesk under Mail Queue

> Messages in queue: 47 deferred, 0 held, 0 incoming, 0 active, 0 corrupted, 47 total.

I was trying many times to re-sending all deferred emails in the queue by taping en console:

> postsuper -r ALL

but the same problem all the time.

Now, when I send mail, exemple:

From: name@mydomainename.com
To: name1@mydomainename.com

it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

Before going into configuration changes, have you checked if your domain is blacklisted or not? Were you able to receive E-mails from other domains such as Gmail?

Sending/receiving Emails to/from the same domain is nearly always possible. No matter how messed up the configurations are you will still manage to deliver emails within the domain itself.

Usually I've found that the reason behind this problem is the blacklisted IPs. Make sure that your domain IP is not blacklisted.

https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

Comment: I can receive mail from gmail and any other domain and about the blacklist my domain listed 2 times in (SORBS SPAM, Suomispam Reputation) with 1 timeouts (CALIVENT) on https://mxtoolbox.com/

Comment: There is your problem. To fix it; simply follow the steps for delisting forms of each blacklist service.